# String from other class .. only get "null"

Tags: java

I want to use a String out of an other class, but I only get `null`.

I tried to get the values with the Code here:

```
System.out.println("Auftrag: " + super.getSollAuftrag1());
System.out.println("Quote: " + super.getSollQuote1());
System.out.println("Teil: " + super.getSollTeil1());
System.out.println("Stueck: " + super.getSollStueck1());
```

---

```
public class ReadText  {
    public static String sollAuftrag1;
    public static String sollQuote1;
    public static String sollTeil1;
    public static String sollStueck1;
    public static String parts;

    public static String getParts() {
        return parts;
    }

    public static void setParts(String parts) {
        ReadText.parts = parts;
    }

    protected String getSollAuftrag1() {
        return sollAuftrag1;
    }

    protected void setSollAuftrag1(String sollAuftrag) {
        ReadText.sollAuftrag1 = sollAuftrag;
    }

    public String getSollQuote1() {
        return sollQuote1;
    }

    public void setSollQuote1(String sollQuote) {
        ReadText.sollQuote1 = sollQuote;
    }

    public String getSollTeil1() {
        return sollTeil1;
    }

    public void setSollTeil1(String sollTeil) {
        ReadText.sollTeil1 = sollTeil;
    }

    public String getSollStueck1() {
        return sollStueck1;
    }

    public void setSollStueck1(String sollStueck) {
        ReadText.sollStueck1 = sollStueck;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader br = null;

        String file_at_path_to_desktop = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\" + "Desktop" + "\\" + "SollAuftrag.txt";

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file_at_path_to_desktop)));

            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(";")));

                String[] parts = line.split(";");

                sollAuftrag1 = (parts[0]);
                sollQuote1 = (parts[1]);
                sollTeil1 = (parts[0]);
                sollStueck1 = (parts[1]);

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            if (br != null) {

                try {

                    br.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println("Auftrag: " + sollAuftrag1);

        System.out.println("Unterauftrag: " + sollQuote1);

        System.out.println("Teil: " + sollTeil1);

        System.out.println("Stueck: " + sollStueck1);


    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - currently your code is incomplete but most of it is still probably irrelevant.

Comment: Please post all relevant code, including how you create those instances of `ReadText`, and where and how you call those `println` statements.

Comment: BTW: Using static fields is probably the wrong thing to do here.

Comment: I can not find this part in the code you posted:  ***System.out.println("Auftrag: " + super.getSollAuftrag1());***